# Is this apparently recurring problem with links just a coincidence? Anyone else seen it?

Tags: discussion

This [proposed edit](https://space.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/10403) to repair a few spaces in front of a link (shown there as "http://%20%20http//library.sciencemadness.org/library/books/ignition.pdf" is the third time in the last week I've seen links contain erroneous characters - including spaces - in the beginning - embedded in posts, in almost the same way. It could be a coincidence, but I don't recall seeing this kind of thing happening widespread before.

I'm just noting it here. If it doesn't continue to recur then this can probably be ignored.

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Someone using a proxy / VPN??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen using the "Insert Hyperlink" button in the Markdown editor, if one somehow manages to type a space or two after the prefilled `http://` in the form, and then pastes in the URL, producing a broken link [like this](http://%20http//meta.space.stackexchange.com/questions/818/is-this-apparently-recurring-problem-with-links-just-a-coincidence-anyone-else).

The code that handles the link insertion will automatically fix URLs with a double `http://` prefix, presumably to avoid errors like this, but inserting a space after the first `http://` confuses it, and it just ends up stripping away the colon after the second `http`.

I would consider this a bug in the SE Markdown editor, even if a rather minor one.

Comment: Thanks - mystery solved! I've never really paid attention to all that stuff at the top.  If I added the `bug` tag, someone will likely [*drive by* and drop a red `by-design` tag next to it](http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/q/766/12102) - effectively making the the issue moot. I think if it were put on a wish list it *might* get some attention, dunno.